# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'exl_cols'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building Python application using two python files, one for the GUI and the other one for functions, in the GUI file I have a button (button1) bonded to a function in the second file (browse_file), in this function am calling another function (exl_cols), but python not accepting calling this function and gives me this error (Event object has no attribute exl_cols)
any help is appreciated

GUI

```
from Browser import Browse
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class DA(Frame):
    #
    # -------Initiating function-----#
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):

        #
        # -------Buttons-------#
        #
        # -------Create browse button-------#
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="Browse", width=16)
        self.button1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", Browse.browse_file)
        self.button1.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='NEW')

Window = Tk()
Window.title("DA Generator")
Window.geometry("600x250")
DATool = DA(Window)
Window.mainloop()
```

Browser

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import os


#
# ---------Excel File Browsing---------#
class Browse:

    #
    # -------Browse for input file-----#
    def browse_file(self):
        global i
        global cols
        self.i = tk.StringVar()
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfile("r")
        self.i.set(self.filename.name)
        self.k = self.filename.name
        self.label3 = tk.Label(text=self.k, bg="White")
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.direc = os.path.dirname(self.i.get())
        self.db = pd.read_excel(io=self.i.get())
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        print(list(self.db.columns))
        if list(self.db.columns) is not None:
            print('excel has columns')
            self.cols = (list(self.db.columns))
            self.exl_cols(self.cols)
        return self.i

        #
        # -------Get excel columns-------#

    def exl_cols(self, x ,*args):
        self.x = tk.StringVar()
        print(tuple(x))
        y = tuple(x)
        global varx
        self.varx = tk.StringVar()
        self.varx.set('Excel Columns')
        self.varx.trace("w", self.mapping)
        cols_menu = tk.OptionMenu(Tk(useTk=0).master, self.varx, *y)
        cols_menu.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky='NEW')
        return self.varx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating `browse_file` as if it were a class function, but it is a method of an instance. Since bindings always pass an event object as the first parameter to the bound function, and because `Browse.browse_file` takes a single argument named `self`, `self` is set to the event object. When you call `self.exl_cols` it's the same as if you called `exl_cols` on the event object. Hence the error `Event object has no attribute exl_cols`

In other words, in your existing code `self` is not what you think it is because of how you call `browse_file`.

You need to create an instance of `Browse` before calling `browse_file`, and you also need to change `browse_file` to accept an event object as a parameter:

```
def browse_file(self, event=None):
    ...
```

Then, this line of code:

```
self.button1.bind(..., Browse.browse_file)
```

...needs to be this:

```
self.button1.bind(..., Browse().browse_file)
```

---

Note: it's usually wrong to use `bind` on a button. You should use the `command` attribute instead (eg: `self.button1 = tk.Button(..., command=Browse().browse_file). If you do that, you don't need to support the`event`argument in`browse_file`.

Comment: I don't have a problem with binding button1 to Browse.browse_file, it is executed normally when I press button1, only the line of self.exl_cols(self.cols) under the function browse_file not executed and gives the error of Event object has no attribute exl_cols

Comment: @MEL46: yes, it gives that error because you aren't creating an instance. The first argument to the function is `self`, so when the binding calls the function, the event is passed in as `self`, hence the error `Event object has no attribute exl_cols`

Comment: @MEL46: I've updated my answer. I hope it's a bit more clear.

Comment: :Many thanks now it works :) , your help is really appreciated